# Prove whether or not the relation is a partial order

Tags: relations

How I would go about proving that the below is or isn't a partial order:

consider the set $\ \mathbb{Z}\ $ of integers:

$aRb \ $ if $\ b = ra \ $ for some positive integer $r$

It adheres to the anti-symmetric property as:

$\ (a,b)\ and\ (b,a)\ \in R \iff r=1\ and\ b=a$

It adheres to the reflexive property as:

$\ (a,a)\ and\ (b,b)\ \in R \iff r=1\ and\ b=a$

Do these suffice as proofs

Comment: What does "$a \mathcal{R} b$ if $b=a$ for some positive integer $r$" mean ? Strictly logically, it means that $\mathcal{R}$ is the equality relation, but I am pretty sure this is not what you want to say.

Comment: $R$ is a relation of the set of integers, so yes $R$ in this case would be the equality relation. I also made a mistake, let me fix

Comment: In your proof, the transitivity is missing.

Comment: I am aware but I don't know how I would go about proving transitivity

Comment: Suppose that $a \mathcal{R} b$ and $b \mathcal{R} c$. Then there exists $r,r'$ such that $a=rb$ and $b=r'c$. Can you find an integer $r''$ such that $a=r''c$ ?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you

Comment: You don't seem to understand what the "reflexive" and "ant-symmetric" mean!  It is not enough that the formulas work for some members of the set, you need to show that they work for **all** members.

Comment: Then how would you prove it? r can be any integer so having a rule based off it being a constant should be fine.